# Websocket handshake problem using Python server

Tags: python, html, websocket

This is a question regarding handshaking in [Websocket Protocol 76](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76).

I have written a client and server, but am having trouble getting the client
to accept the handshake. I can see that it is being returned, but the client immediately closes the connection. I'm guessing that my md5sum response must be incorrect.

As far as I can tell, I'm following the proper procedure, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
def create_handshake_resp(handshake):

  # parse request
  final_line = ""
  lines = handshake.splitlines()
  for line in lines:
    parts = line.partition(":")
    if parts[0] == "Sec-WebSocket-Key1":
      key1 = parts[2]
    elif parts[0] == "Sec-WebSocket-Key2":
      key2 = parts[2]
    final_line = line

  #concat the keys and encrypt
  e = hashlib.md5()
  e.update(parse_key(key1))
  e.update(parse_key(key2))
  e.update(final_line)
  return "HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake\r\nUpgrade: WebSocket\r\nConnection:     Upgrade\r\nWebSocket-Origin: http://%s\r\nWebSocket-Location: ws://%s/\r\nWebSocket-Protocol: sample\r\n\r\n%s" % (httphost, sockethost, e.digest())



def parse_key(key):

  spaces = -1
  digits = ""
  for c in key:
    if c == " ":
      spaces += 1
    if is_number(c):
      digits = digits + c


  new_key = int(digits) / spaces
  return str(new_key)
```

As you can see, I am performing what I think to be the correct operations on the keys (divide numbers by space count, concat results and the last line of the request and then MD5) and a 16 byte response is definitely being returned.

Any help would be much appreciated, and as soon as I have a working copy I will post it here.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Changed the headers to comply with kanaka's response. Handshake is still not being accepted by the client.
I found out how to display the requests in Chromium, and this is the request and response being given:

```
(P) t=1291739663323 [st=3101]     WEB_SOCKET_SEND_REQUEST_HEADERS  
                              --> GET / HTTP/1.1   
                                  Upgrade: WebSocket
                                  Connection: Upgrade
                                  Host: ---
                                  Origin: http://---
                                  Sec-WebSocket-Key1: 3E 203C 220 642;
                                  Sec-WebSocket-Key2: Lg 590 ~5 703O G7  =%t 9
                                                   
                                  \x74\x66\xef\xab\x50\x60\x35\xc6\x0a
(P) t=1291739663324 [st=3102]     SOCKET_STREAM_SENT     
(P) t=1291739663348 [st=3126]     SOCKET_STREAM_RECEIVED  
(P) t=1291739663348 [st=3126]     WEB_SOCKET_READ_RESPONSE_HEADERS  
                              --> HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake
                                  Upgrade: WebSocket
                                  Connection: Upgrade
                                  Sec-WebSocket-Origin: http://---
                                  Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://---/
                                  Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: sample
                                                   
                                  \xe7\x6f\xb9\xcf\xae\x70\x57\x43\xc6\x20\x85\xe7\x39\x2e\x83\xec\x0
```

Ad verbatim, except I've removed the IP address for obvious reasons.

Comment: Your indentation doesn't make sense. I presume the lines `#concat`..`return` are meant to be in `create_handshake_resp`?

Comment: Sorry. Copy and paste mistake. Edited.

Comment: You needed the `spaces = -1` because you are not ignoring the first space after `:` in the header (e.g `Sec-WebSocket-Key1: a b` only contains one space, as far as the response is concerned). Doing `line.partition(": ")` prevents this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple problems that immediately jump out at me:

- You aren't counting spaces properly. You counter should start at 0 not -1.
- Your response headers are still v75 style. Any header starting with "WebSocket-"  (WebSocket-Origin, WebSocket-Location, WebSocket-Protocol) should instead start with "Sec-WebSocket-" in v76.

Here is how I calculate the response chksum in wsproxy (part of [noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) an HTML5 VNC client):

```
import struct, md5
...
spaces1 = key1.count(" ")
spaces2 = key2.count(" ")
num1 = int("".join([c for c in key1 if c.isdigit()])) / spaces1
num2 = int("".join([c for c in key2 if c.isdigit()])) / spaces2

return md5(struct.pack('>II8s', num1, num2, key3)).digest()
```

Comment: The space count starting at -1 is because when the string is split there is a space in between the : and the key, which shouldn't be counted.

I'll try changing the headers to 76, I didn't notice that they had changed. Thanks for your help, I'll let you know the outcome.

Comment: Still no luck, but I've updated the question to show the request and response.

Comment: Whahey! I changed my code to your response code and it works :) though I had to include the -1 on spaces.Not sure what was wrong with mine but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of a WebSocket client/server (client in Javascript, server in Python 2.6)

It used examples from various places (including kanaka's answer/noVNC, and [this page](http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2010/6/7/living-on-the-edge-of-the-websocket-protocol) and [this page](http://dev.enekoalonso.com/2010/05/22/more-websockets-now-with-python/))

Works with Chrome 10.0.648.127, Safari 5.0.3 and MobileSafari on iPad from iOS 4.3

It's by no means well written code (the example HTML page is especially terrible) - use at your own risk and so on..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import threading
import struct
import hashlib

PORT = 9876


def create_handshake_resp(handshake):
    final_line = ""
    lines = handshake.splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        parts = line.partition(": ")
        if parts[0] == "Sec-WebSocket-Key1":
            key1 = parts[2]
        elif parts[0] == "Sec-WebSocket-Key2":
            key2 = parts[2]
        elif parts[0] == "Host":
            host = parts[2]
        elif parts[0] == "Origin":
            origin = parts[2]
        final_line = line

    spaces1 = key1.count(" ")
    spaces2 = key2.count(" ")
    num1 = int("".join([c for c in key1 if c.isdigit()])) / spaces1
    num2 = int("".join([c for c in key2 if c.isdigit()])) / spaces2

    token = hashlib.md5(struct.pack('>II8s', num1, num2, final_line)).digest()

    return (
        "HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake\r\n"
        "Upgrade: WebSocket\r\n"
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
        "Sec-WebSocket-Origin: %s\r\n"
        "Sec-WebSocket-Location: ws://%s/\r\n"
        "\r\n"
        "%s") % (
        origin, host, token)


def handle(s, addr):
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.send(create_handshake_resp(data))
    lock = threading.Lock()

    while 1:
        print "Waiting for data from", s, addr
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print "Done"
        if not data:
            print "No data"
            break

        print 'Data from', addr, ':', data

        # Broadcast received data to all clients
        lock.acquire()
        [conn.send(data) for conn in clients]
        lock.release()

    print 'Client closed:', addr
    lock.acquire()
    clients.remove(s)
    lock.release()
    s.close()

def start_server():
    s = socket.socket()
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(('', PORT))
    s.listen(1)
    while 1:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print 'Connected by', addr
        clients.append(conn)
        threading.Thread(target = handle, args = (conn, addr)).start()

clients = []
start_server()
```

Also, a crappy example HTML page to show it working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="application/javascript">
            var ws;

            function init() {
                var servermsg = document.getElementById("servermsg");

                ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9876/");
                ws.onopen = function(){
                    servermsg.innerHTML = servermsg.innerHTML + "<br>Server connected";
                    servermsg.innerHTML = servermsg.innerHTML + "<br>Sending message to server";
                    ws.send("Hello Mr. Server!");
                };
                ws.onmessage = function(e){
                    servermsg.innerHTML = servermsg.innerHTML + "<br>Recieved data: " + e.data;
                };
                ws.onclose = function(){
                    console.log("Server disconnected");
                    servermsg.innerHTML = servermsg.innerHTML + "<br>Connected";
                };
            }
            function postmsg(){
                var text = document.getElementById("message").value;
                ws.send(text);
                servermsg.innerHTML = servermsg.innerHTML + "<br>Sent: " + text;
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <form action="" onSubmit="postmsg()">
            <input type="text" name="message" value="" id="message">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="submit">
        </form>
        <div id="servermsg"><h1>Message log:</h1></div>
    </body>
</html>
```